# Create Table with calculated column using a javascript function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looking to create a table and include a calculated column that references a javascript function.  I have found that I can do calculations in the calculated column using as case statement.

but I created the following function, cant seem to get it to work with the calculated column. Do you know if this is functionality I am just using wrong or not currently supported?

```
create or replace function UTILITY.function.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT_test
(COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX varchar, COLUMN_NAME varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
AS $$
    return COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX + ':' + COLUMN_NAME
$$
;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DEV_BCOLEMAN.dev.T2(
  SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME varchar,
  SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX varchar,
  SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT varchar(100) AS (UTILITY.function.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT_TEST(SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX, SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME))
);
```

Hoping the output would look something like this:

| SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME | SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX | SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | data | data:id |

Couple of the ways I tried:
`SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT varchar(100) as UTILITY.FUNCTION.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT('data','id')`

`SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT varchar(100) as (select UTILITY.FUNCTION.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT('data', 'id')`

The error is::   Invalid virtual column expression [JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT..]

Comment: You can absolutely return computed values from JavaScript UDFs and use them to build tables. Can you include the body of the JavaScript UDF (or the relevant sections if it's very long) and a sample of what you want for its output?

Comment: Updated the original with a bit more, still pretty basic but holds the general pieces.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use scalar SQL UDF as virtual column's expression:

```
create or replace function PUBLIC.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT
(COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX varchar)
returns varchar
AS 'COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX';
```

Demo:

```
SELECT PUBLIC.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT('id');
-- id

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T2(
  i INT,
  SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT varchar(100) AS (PUBLIC.JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT('id'))
);

INSERT INTO t2(i) VALUES (1);
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see, so you can use a SQL UDF, but not a Javascript UDF

Answer (score 2):

In order to do what you're attempting here, you need to use the DEFAULT keyword for the column. Snowflake supports the following three types of DEFAULT values for columns:

- Constant value
- Simple expression
- Sequence reference (seq_name.NEXTVAL)

A JavaScript UDF probably does not qualify as a simple expression, but what you want here can be done using a simple expression that the DEFAULT value will use:

```
create or replace function JSON_TO_TABLE_SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT_test
(COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX varchar, COLUMN_NAME varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
AS $$
    return COLUMN_NAME_PREFIX + ':' + COLUMN_NAME
$$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T2(
  SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME varchar,
  SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX varchar,
  SOURCE_COLUMN_TEXT varchar(100) default SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX || ':' || SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME
);

insert into t2 (SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME, SOURCE_COLUMN_PREFIX) values ('ID', 'DATA');

select * from t2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't default will work for this use.  If the table is updated, I would need the calculation to update. to my knowledge default is only updated on the insert and is not updated if values on the table change.  I will see what I can make work with a SQL UDF

Comment: You could of course use a view in that case. Just add a column to the view that's a concatenation of the two values in those columns.